# Typescript - Morgan and logger.stream cause lint error

Tags: typescript, express, winston, compiled, morgan

I try to attach `Morgan` log to `Winston` using a logger Stream feature.
But once I try to attach the `logger.stream` when I use morgan middleware, it fails with this message:

`Argument of type '"combined"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormatFn'.`

Here is my Winston init code:

```
import * as appRoot from 'app-root-path';
import * as winston from 'winston';
import { Logger } from 'winston';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as stream from 'stream';

const dirLogs = `${appRoot}/logs`;

// It's call during initialization, we can block the thread
if (!fs.existsSync(dirLogs)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(dirLogs);
}
// define the custom settings for each transport (file, console)
const options = {
  file: {
    level: 'info',
    filename: `${dirLogs}/app.log`,
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: true,
    maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
    maxFiles: 5,
    colorize: false,
  },
  console: {
    level: 'debug',
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: false,
    colorize: true,
  },
};

// Keep it simple to focus on the need first
// I think Logger should send logs to a logger service
const logger = new Logger({
  level: 'info',
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File(options.file),
    new winston.transports.Console(options.console),
  ],
  exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
});

// If I don't use the stream.Duplex, it cause another lint error.
logger.stream = (options?: any) => new stream.Duplex({
  write: function (message: string, encoding: any) {
      logger.info(message.trim());
  }
});

export default logger;
```

And then, the code where I try to use Morgan with.

```
// ... All import
import logger from './logger/index';

// ... Then later the code
this.expressApp.use(morgan('combined', { stream: logger.stream }));
```

I'm not sure to understand why I got this error :/

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I deep down in the code and the typescript files to understand what it really needs to be done.

I changed my `logger.stream` declaration from

```
// If I don't use the stream.Duplex, it cause another lint error.
logger.stream = (options?: any) => new stream.Duplex({
  write: function (message: string, encoding: any) {
      logger.info(message.trim());
  }
});
```

To

```
// Don't forget this import
import { Options } from 'morgan';

// And the code
export const morganOption: Options = {
  stream: {
    write: function (message: string) {
        logger.info(message.trim());
    },
  },
};
```

Then I import the `morganOptions` and set it to `morgan`

```
// My import
import { logger, morganOption } from './logger/index';

// ... Then later, the new code
this.expressApp.use(morgan('combined', morganOption));
```

Hope it helps others :)

Answer (score 0):

Install the Winston node package with node package manager

Create a logger.ts add the following code to it

```
import { createLogger, format, transports } from 'winston';
const { label, combine, timestamp , prettyPrint } = format;
const logger = createLogger({
 format: combine(
 timestamp(),
 prettyPrint(),
 ),
 transports: [
 new transports.Console(),
 new transports.File({ filename: './error.log' , level: 'error' }),
 new transports.File({ filename: './info.log' , level: 'info' }),
 ],
 exitOnError: false,
});
export default loggerStep
```

See more in the line below
[enter link description here](https://truetocode.com/logging-in-node-js-express-application-using-winston-logger/)